# If $p=1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 \cdot ... \cdot 2011$, then the units digit of $p$ is five

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I know there is a $5$ on the sequence, but i don't know how and why his presence leads to the final units digit of the product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: All odd numbers divisible by $5$ end in $5$.

Comment: I just love how succinctly and quickly he draws this problem to a quick end.

Comment: short and sweet.